# How can I add an external Python file to my restructured text document?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I want to write a book using Sphinx and restructured text. As most of the content
will be solutions written in Python I want to separate the text and the code.

**Is there a command to add external python scripts to my restructured text documents?**

I tried to use

```
.. code-block:: python
    .. include:: unittest_exp1.py
```

and

```
.. code-block:: python
    .. file:: unittest_exp1.py
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use literalinclude as shown in the Sphinx documentation.

```
.. literalinclude:: example.py
   :language: python
   :emphasize-lines: 12,15-18
   :linenos:
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you try [.. literalinclude:: filename](http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/code.html)?

Here is a little [example](http://thomas-cokelaer.info/tutorials/sphinx/_sources/rest_syntax.txt):

```
.. literalinclude:: filename
    :linenos:
    :language: python
    :lines: 1, 7-8 
    :start-after: 12
    :end-before: 5
```