# Pass code type to Sphinx `.. include::` directive

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I want to include full example scripts in Sphinx documentation.  I originally simply duplicated an example file using a `.. code::` directive, dropping in the entire python and json files for the example.

I then found the `.. include::` directive, which lets to link to files by providing their relative path, and by using the `code` option, "[The argument and the included content are passed to the code directive](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#including-an-external-document-fragment)".  This works fine for my python files, because the default decoding and highlighting for the code directive is python.  But my json files are not highlighted as json.  How do I indicate what code format the code directive should use to parse the code?

This is what I am using.

```
.. include:: ../../examples/my_example.json
    :code:
```

I tried adding changing the second line to `:code: json` with no effect.

This is what I had originally, but want to replace so the example code does not have to be maintained in both the documentation and the examples.

```json
.. code-block:: json
    :name: my_example.json
    :caption: my_example.json

    {
        "field1": "attribute1",
        "field2": "attribute2",
        "field3": true,
        ...
    }
```

Comment: It seems like `literalinclude` is what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18801693/407651

Comment: @mzjn thank you, much appreciated!

Comment: Changing the second line to `:code: json` should help. You may need to set the Docutils config setting [syntax-highlight](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/user/config.html#syntax-highlight) to "short" so that the markup is compatible with Pygments-generated stylesheets.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to instead use the [`literalinclude` directive](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-literalinclude) which has a `language` option.  This is how it should look.

```
.. literalinclude:: ../../examples/my_example.json
    :language: json
```

Note that literal include also supports options like `linenos`, `lines`, `start-after`, and `end-before`, `caption`, and `name`.